# How to fill dataframe with another dataframe by condition and sum when it on same cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 2 dataframes df1 and df2 as shown down below.

df1 illustrate quantity data of each column name. So each column will contain quantity from Floor to Under.

```
    Column name    Floor    Under  ConcType   ConcTotal     RebarTotal     SteelTotal
0   CB1            ACP      GF     C80        21.6          7954.8         2265.0
1   CB1A           B4F      LGF    C60        1.2           318.8          0.0
...   
201 CT12B          GF       8F     C60        4.5           757.6         840.0
202 CT13A          GF       8F     C80        1.4           429.3         420.0
```

And df2 is a form for infill quantity data separate floor.But df2 is different on Fl.Name_h (column) mean will contain quantity of all column form df1 to carry that Floor.

H mean Height of column to carry that Floor. It is calculated by Elevation Floor - Elevation previous Floor.

For example H of Floor F8 is 48400 - 42800 = 5600

```
    Fl.Name_Elev    Elevation    Fl.Name_h   H         C60_Conc  C80_Conc   Rebar   Steel
0   8F              48400        8F          5600.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN 
1   7F              42800        7F          6000.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
2   6F              36800        6F          6000.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
3   5F              30800        5F          5600.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
4   4F              25200        4F          5600.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
5   3F              19600        3F          5600.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
6   2F              14000        2F          6000.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
7   1F              8000         1F          6000.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
8   GF              2000         GF          3300.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
9   LGF MZ          -1300        LGF MZ      3150.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN 
10  LGF             -4450        LGF         4650.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
11  B1F             -9100        B1F         3000.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
12  B2F             -12100       B2F         3000.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
13  B3F             -15100       B3F         4650.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN 
14  B4F             -19750       B4F         8250.0    NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
15  ACP             -28000       NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN     NaN
```

I would like to fill up from df1 into NaN  of "C60_Conc", "C80_Conc","Rebar","Steel" in df2.

The Result will look like :

```
Fl.Name_Elev    Elevation    Fl.Name_h       H         C60_Conc C80_Conc    Rebar    Steel
0   8F              48400        8F          5600.0    4.5      1.4         1186.9   1260   
1   7F              42800        7F          6000.0    4.5      1.4         1186.9   1260
2   6F              36800        6F          6000.0    4.5      1.4         1186.9   1260
3   5F              30800        5F          5600.0    4.5      1.4         1186.9   1260
4   4F              25200        4F          5600.0    4.5      1.4         1186.9   1260
5   3F              19600        3F          5600.0    4.5      1.4         1186.9   1260
6   2F              14000        2F          6000.0    4.5      1.4         1186.9   1260
7   1F              8000         1F          6000.0    4.5      1.4         1186.9   1260
8   GF              2000         GF          3300.0    0        21.6        7954.8   2265
9   LGF MZ          -1300        LGF MZ      3150.0    0        21.6        7954.8   2265   
10  LGF             -4450        LGF         4650.0    1.2      21.6        8276.6   2265
11  B1F             -9100        B1F         3000.0    1.2      21.6        8276.6   2265
12  B2F             -12100       B2F         3000.0    1.2      21.6        8276.6   2265
13  B3F             -15100       B3F         4650.0    1.2      21.6        8276.6   2265   
14  B4F             -19750       B4F         8250.0    0        21.6        7954.8   2265
15  ACP             -28000       NaN         NaN       NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN
```

P.S. Sorry for my communication. English isn't my mother tongue.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want in `C60_Conc`? Only part of the column is visible in your output. Also are the values in your first DataFrame exactly like `21.6(a0)`? Or is it just `21.6`?

Comment: In df1, If ConcType is C60 it will be fill in C60_Conc in df2. 
 If ConcType is C80 it will be fill in C80_Conc in df2.  

df1 it just exactly 21.6

Comment: Please can you update the question showing the actual values in the DataFrame and also in the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

```
floors = df2["Fl.Name_Elev"].tolist()[::-1]
df1["Floors"] = df1.apply(lambda x: floors[floors.index(x["Floor"]):floors.index(x["Under"])+1], axis=1)
df1 = df1.explode(column=["Floors"])
mapper = df1.pivot(index=df1.columns.difference(["ConcType", "ConcTotal"]), 
                   columns="ConcType", 
                   values="ConcTotal").reset_index().groupby("Floors").sum()
output = df2.merge(mapper, left_on="Fl.Name_Elev", right_index=True, how="left")
output = output.rename(columns={"C60": "C60_Conc", "C80": "C80_Conc"})
>>> output
   Fl.Name_Elev  Elevation Fl.Name_h  ...  SteelTotal  C60_Conc  C80_Conc
0            8F      48400        8F  ...        1260       4.5       1.4
1            7F      42800        7F  ...        1260       4.5       1.4
2            6F      36800        6F  ...        1260       4.5       1.4
3            5F      30800        5F  ...        1260       4.5       1.4
4            4F      25200        4F  ...        1260       4.5       1.4
5            3F      19600        3F  ...        1260       4.5       1.4
6            2F      14000        2F  ...        1260       4.5       1.4
7            1F       8000        1F  ...        1260       4.5       1.4
8            GF       2000        GF  ...        3525       4.5      23.0
9        LGF MZ      -1300    LGF MZ  ...        2265       0.0      21.6
10          LGF      -4450       LGF  ...        2265       1.2      21.6
11          B1F      -9100       B1F  ...        2265       1.2      21.6
12          B2F     -12100       B2F  ...        2265       1.2      21.6
13          B3F     -15100       B3F  ...        2265       1.2      21.6
14          B4F     -19750       B4F  ...        2265       1.2      21.6
15          ACP     -28000       NaN  ...        2265       0.0      21.6
```

### Explanation

First, we include all the floors in df1 from Floor to Under using `pandas.explode`:

```
floors = df2["Fl.Name_Elev"].tolist()[::-1]
df1["Floors"] = df1.apply(lambda x: floors[floors.index(x["Floor"]):floors.index(x["Under"])+1], axis=1)
df1 = df1.explode(column=["Floors"])
>>> df1.head()
  Column name Floor Under ConcType  ConcTotal  RebarTotal  SteelTotal  Floors
0         CB1   ACP    GF      C80       21.6      7954.8        2265     ACP
0         CB1   ACP    GF      C80       21.6      7954.8        2265     B4F
0         CB1   ACP    GF      C80       21.6      7954.8        2265     B3F
0         CB1   ACP    GF      C80       21.6      7954.8        2265     B2F
0         CB1   ACP    GF      C80       21.6      7954.8        2265     B1F
0         CB1   ACP    GF      C80       21.6      7954.8        2265     LGF
0         CB1   ACP    GF      C80       21.6      7954.8        2265  LGF MZ
0         CB1   ACP    GF      C80       21.6      7954.8        2265      GF
1        CB1A   B4F   LGF      C60        1.2       318.8           0     B4F
1        CB1A   B4F   LGF      C60        1.2       318.8           0     B3F
```

Then, we create a mapper by using `pandas.pivot` to get separate columns for C60 and C80 and use `pandas.groupby` with `sum` to get the total for each floor:

```
mapper = df1.pivot(index=df1.columns.difference(["ConcType", "ConcTotal"]),
                   columns="ConcType",
                   values="ConcTotal") \
            .reset_index() \
            .groupby("Floor").sum()
>>> mapper
ConcType  RebarTotal  SteelTotal  C60   C80
Floors                                     
1F            1186.9        1260  4.5   1.4
2F            1186.9        1260  4.5   1.4
3F            1186.9        1260  4.5   1.4
4F            1186.9        1260  4.5   1.4
5F            1186.9        1260  4.5   1.4
6F            1186.9        1260  4.5   1.4
7F            1186.9        1260  4.5   1.4
8F            1186.9        1260  4.5   1.4
ACP           7954.8        2265  0.0  21.6
B1F           8273.6        2265  1.2  21.6
B2F           8273.6        2265  1.2  21.6
B3F           8273.6        2265  1.2  21.6
B4F           8273.6        2265  1.2  21.6
GF            9141.7        3525  4.5  23.0
LGF           8273.6        2265  1.2  21.6
LGF MZ        7954.8        2265  0.0  21.6
```

Lastly, we use `pandas.merge` on df2 and mapper to get the output:

```
output = df2.merge(mapper, left_on="Fl.Name_Elev", right_index=True, how="left")
output = output.rename(columns={"C60": "C60_Conc", "C80": "C80_Conc"})
```

Comment: This is very satisfy. I just adjust a little bit it work fit for me.                              
`df1["Floors"] = df1.apply(lambda x: floors[floors.index(x["Floor"])+1:floors.index(x["Under"])+1], axis=1)`  and  `.groupby("Floors").sum()`     Many thank sir.